# Multiple requests using Retrofit and RXJava

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java

I have a service called *verifyData*. I need call this service N number of times.

- **Retrofit 2**
- **RXJava**

Service

```
@FormUrlEncoded
   @POST("verifyData")
   Observable<Adeudos> Adeudos(
           @Field("id") int id_user    
   );
```

Simple Call

```
Observable<Adeudos> respuesta = services.verifyData(1);
respuesta.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                 .subscribe(new Subscriber<Adeudos>() {
                     @Override
                     public void onCompleted() {
                     }

                     @Override
                     public void onError(Throwable e) {

                     }

                     @Override
                     public void onNext(Adeudos adeudos) {

                     }
                 });
```

I need execute this "method" usign this array

```
List<String> ids = new ArrayList(); // 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

**SOLUTION**

Add [retrolambda](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrolambda/article.html) in my gradle

**Java**

```
 Observable.from(ids)
               .flatMap(s -> services.verifyData(ids).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
               .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
               .subscribe(new Subscriber<Adeudos>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onCompleted() {
                       Log.e("Completed :"," Completed\n");    
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onError(Throwable e) {
                       Log.e("SplashInteractorImpl :       ",e.getMessage()+"\n");

                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onNext(Adeudos adeudos) {
                        Log.e("SplashInteractorImpl :       ",adeudos.getMessage()+"\n");
                   }
               });
```

Comment: You should be able to do this with `Observable.zip()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to make sequential calls, use `.concatMap`

```
    Observable.from(ids)
            .concatMap(s -> services.verifyData(Integer.parseInt(s)))
            //subscription
```

If you want parallel calls, use a `flatMap()` with a `maxConcurrent` parameter

```
    Observable.from(ids)
            .flatMap(s -> services.verifyData(Integer.parseInt(s))
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()), maxConcurrent)
            //subscription
```

So it creates stream of `id` from your list and modifies it to make your api calls.

Comment: But i need minSdkVersion: 24 :/  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=207493

Comment: Use retrolambda or anonymous classes

Comment: thanks! work fine using retrolambda  : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrolambda/article.html